# Protege: How to specify restrictions on data properties?

Tags: string, ontology, restriction, protege

I'm creating an ontology using Protege and would like to specifiy restrictions on data properties. Let's say there is a data property named `hasCode`. I've defined `string` as range and would like to further define that the maximum length is 3 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protege in OWL2 allows you to use the Manchester syntax to define data range expressions.
Open the range window, and enter a data range expression.

In this case to limit the length, you can have string[length x].

For more, see http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/

[image: expression window]